# How to enable remote management operations in Wildfly

Tags: java, wildfly

Trying to read some values from my standalone.xml in Wildfly, I have got the following error message:

```
{
    "outcome" => "failed",
    "failure-description" => "WFLYCTL0379: System boot is in process; execution of remote management operations is not currently available"
}
```

In JBoss 7.1.1 it works fine, please see my java coding inside Ejb Singleton:

```
@Startup
@Singleton
@ConcurrencyManagement(ConcurrencyManagementType.BEAN)
public class TestBean {
    @PostConstruct
    private void init() throws Exception {
                final ModelNode request = new ModelNode();
                request.get(ClientConstants.OP).set("read-resource");
                request.get("recursive").set(true);
                request.get(ClientConstants.OP_ADDR).add("subsystem", "security");

                final ModelControllerClient client = ModelControllerClient.Factory.create(InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1"),
                        9029);
                final ModelNode response = client.execute(new OperationBuilder(request).build());
    }
}
```

This error comes at the moment when the client.execute() tries to get ModelNode.

I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: I wouldn't advise doing this. What is it you're trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know what El Lord Code was trying to accomplish, but in my project, for example, we are using the pattern of Startup Singleton to initialize the application. Now, during that thing, we need to do some programatic login - logout to Wildfly and the logout does some credential cache flushing which depends on acccessing the security domain. The problem is that this whole remote management is not accessible during startup and shutdown (it starts after and ends before the application is started / stopped).
I have posted a similar question here: https://developer.jboss.org/message/944842#944842

Answer (score 0):

The Error is stating that Wildfly is still deploying some WAR/application

In this period the management is still not accessible.

Try to start the Wildfly without any applications in deployment folder and then try to read the standalone config for what ever needs.